# CKEditor Within Form Image Upload - Laravel 5.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, ckeditor, image-uploading, laravel-5.4

I have just integrated `CKEditor` within a `form`. And it shows up great. I am trying to kind of attach image to CKEditor content area. I want to do few things.

1. Upload some image (local / URL ).
2. Show this image within the content area.

The problem with this is `image` button from the toolbar opens up a dialogbox to upload image OR type `URL` but this field seems to be kind of disabled.

[image: CKEditor Image Upload DialogBox]